# overload the ActionResult in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Please provide direction if this is a good idea or not....

I have a customer that wants VERY detailed application logging in the system.  They want to track every click and the page and control that was clicked.

I was thinking that a nice stored procedure on the SQL server would allow me to keep that information, but getting that level of information into the database is the question.

I was thinking about adding a single entry in the EF to post the information into the SQL server within every ActionResult block of code, but it occured to me, that maybe i can just override the ActionResult and do it that way....

anyone ever do anything like that?

tia

Comment: If they want page level tracking you'll have to use AJAX as well, and monitor that somehow.

Comment: @OP: I think your premise is correct. There has to be a way of overriding a routing function in a base class somewhere. Interesting question, +1!

Comment: I am sure there are tools out there that do what you need. To start with, free google analytics provide you with a lot of details about clicks and other user stats. There are commercial tools (cannot recall any names though) which collect and display stats in real time. It is worth googling for them first.

Comment: GA does not give enough detailed information, further, this website is totally blocked from outside world interaction.   thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log all kinds of thing using `ActionFilters`. This [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) even has a logging example. By the way, the same action filters also can help you during debugging, so you see what happened before the exception.

And if your customer want super crazy trace info, you can log [MiniProfiler's logging and tracing information](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/07/25/Automatically+instrumenting+an+MVC3+app), that contains all kinds of extra info like actual db calls and things like that.

But as Andre already mentioned, use a different db, and save the results asynchronously.

#### Edit:

This method logs what actually happened in the application, the actual results of user actions, if your customer needs logging for auditing, or something like that, `ActionFilters` are for you.

If your customer wants to track usage statistics, something like a [web page heat map](https://www.google.hu/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=web%20page%20heat%20map&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest), well, look at the search results :-)

Comment: PERFECT - spot on answer!!   THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

**this is not an aswer**, but there is one point that you must consider and I'd like to discuss it.

If you need tracking log with so much detail (like where the user clicked at the page), them I'd strongly suggest you to *don't store these logs on the same database that the app uses*, because scalability will be a problem.
Moreover, tracking logs are a good match for a NoSQL database. As most of these databases work with a REST API, turns out that this is a perfect solution to track user interaction using javascript.

Think about it. You'll have an isolated REST webservice to store your tracking logs. They can be sent from C# (from a Controller or wherever) and from the view, easily.

Any feedback will be appreciated. As I said, this is not an answer, but think of it as a brainstorming.

Regards

Comment: NoSQL databases only really make sense when the data is non-relational or where each object to be stored differs from others (i.e. as a way of storing blobs). However tracking data is relational and shares a common structure - I don't see how using a NoSQL platform offers any advantages whereas an RDBMS would allow for easier analysis of the data in aggregate.

Comment: Excellent point - the load on the SQL server might / will be a problem...   I have already talked to the IT staff, and they are standing up a new SQL server as we speak.   thanks for the reply!

Comment: @David tracking logs usually don't relate with each others, it's just a "snapshot" of an action, which is one point for a NoSQL database. Also, the schemaless rule of a NoSQL database is also a strong point for this scenario. Consider that logs from the view (page itself) may have a set of data different from logs gathered from server side. Also, the log structure may change over time. Also, there are lots of scenarios for NoSQL databases, other then storing blobs.